# android disable onclick event when url links clicked

Tags: android, events, textview

I have `textview` which contains `urls` like *www.google.com*.  for this `textview` a have also created a onclicklistener.

My problem is when user clickes *www.google.com,* link is used by an `activity`, but after that `activity` `onclick` event is also created. but i dont want to create `onclick` events when user clicks on urls .

Is it possible for texview to disable `onclick` events when user clickes on urls like *http://www.google.com, market://android.. etc.*

EDIT 1: I added details below.

```
            TextView entry = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.textViewEntryText);
            entry.setText(Html.fromHtml(String.format("%s",
                    (CharSequence) displayText)));
            entry.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

after creating textview with links then put another events onclick other texts.

```
            entry.setOnClickListener((new View.OnClickListener() {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                }
            }));
```

Now when user clicks on url link i dont want to other onclick event works for links .

Comment: I think you have to clarify your question a little further. Is what you want clickable textviews without the action as links?

Comment: @techiServices's answer might be more accurate actually, have you tried that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

wow. Android is magic. There is a seperate [attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLinksClickable%28boolean%29) for that:

```
android:linksClickable:"false"
```

You can change it in the code, via :

```
myTextView.setLinksClickable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:autoLink` in the XML or `TextView.setAutoLinkMask(int)` to control whether links are searched for.