# No Activity found (browser) with valid http:// prefix

Tags: android, android-activity, activitynotfoundexception

So I got an exception from my app as follows:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://google.com (has extras) }
    at  android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1512)
    at  android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
    at  android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3248)
    at  android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:839)
    at  android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3359)
    at  android.text.style.URLSpan.onClick(URLSpan.java:62)
    at  android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod.onTouchEvent(LinkMovementMethod.java:212)
    at  android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:8704)
    at  android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5556)
    at  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
    at  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
    at  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
    at  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
    at  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
    at  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
    at  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
    at  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
    at  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
    at  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
    at  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
    at  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
    at  com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1940)
    at  com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1390)
    at  android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2414)
    at  com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1888)
    at  android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5736)
    at  android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3017)
    at  android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2582)
    at  android.view.ViewRootImpl.processInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:887)
    at  android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2591)
    at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4697)
    at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
    at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
    at  dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This doesn't lead to my code. I assume this happens when user clicks URL in the text (and there are texts with URLs in app). What it's about? How could it be that Android device doesn't have a browser? How to bypass this or at least to catch (I need URLs be clickable in text)?

**UPDATE**
Actually I found that this exception happens in TextView which is intended to be an empty list view stub:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
// empty pass list with clickable url inside
final TextView listEmptyView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNoPasses);
listEmptyView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
listView.setEmptyView(listEmptyView);
```

So I tried this (following CommonsWare's article) but my URL remains completely unclickable in this case:

```
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    // empty pass list with clickable url inside
    final TextView listEmptyView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNoPasses);
    fixTextView(listEmptyView);
    listView.setEmptyView(listEmptyView);
}

private void fixTextView(TextView textView) {
    final SpannableString current = new SpannableString(textView.getText());
    final URLSpan[] spans = current.getSpans(0, current.length(), URLSpan.class);
    int start, end;
    for (URLSpan span : spans) {
        start = current.getSpanStart(span);
        end = current.getSpanEnd(span);
        current.removeSpan(span);
        current.setSpan(new DefensiveURLSpan(span.getURL()), start, end, 0);
    }
}

private static class DefensiveURLSpan extends URLSpan {
      public DefensiveURLSpan(String url) {
        super(url);
      }

      @Override
      public void onClick(View widget) {
        try {
          android.util.Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Got here!");
          super.onClick(widget);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
          // do something useful here
          // android.text.SpannedString cannot be cast to android.text.SpannableString
        }
      }
}
```

And TextView:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNoPasses"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="@string/no_passes"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
```

And `no_passes` string is following:

```
<string name="no_passes">Currently you have no cards to use.\n<a href="http://cardz.website.com">You could add some cards from our website</a></string>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that this is a TextView with [`android:autolink`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:autoLink) set, or that otherwise displays HTML (for example, using `Html.fromHtml()`).

The problems is that this creates [`URLSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/URLSpan.html) instances for embedded URIs, and this class "blindly" calls `startActivity()` with the supplied URI. This crashes whenever the URI does not match with any registered activity. For "http" URLS this can happen when the device doesn't have a browser application, or (more likely) when using a [restricted profile](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html#RestrictedProfiles) that blocks access to it.

The problem and its solution is well explained in [this CommonsWare post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/10/23/linkify-autolink-need-custom-urlspan.html). You can replace the `URLSpan` instances with a custom derived class that intercepts `onClick()` to avoid the exception.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26618190/82788) for a related issue.

Comment: This is almost the answer. However I use nor URLSpan neither Linkify but setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()) and I have no idea how to apply CommonsWare's article to this. The only visible way for me now - is to follow Jeff Mixon's answer to apply or don't the setMovementMethod().

Comment: @Stan The solution should be the same, as `URLSpan` is used behind the scenes (as you can see from the exception stack). You should be able to copy `fixTextView()` from the post as is.

Comment: Actually I already tried it together with removing setMovementMethod() but the link stays not clickable as a result. Did I miss something? I'll add the code to my question.

Comment: @Stan Don't remove `setMovementMethod()`, that is ok. Just adding the `fixTextView()` after `setText()` should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible for an Android device not to have a browser. It is not required, per say, but obviously pretty rare. Android-ish devices like Kindles come to mind, although they still would have a browser...

Nonetheless, you can disable URL linking in your `TextView` as follows:

```
textView.setLinksClickable(false);
```

Also, [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533853/android-disable-onclick-event-when-url-links-clicked).

**Edit**

See [this answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12961338/1489860)

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
PackageManager manager = mContext.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> list = manager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
    //You have at least one activity to handle the intent
} else {
    //No activity to handle the intent.
}
```

Create a new intent with `ACTION_VIEW` and a url and use this pattern to determine whether or not the device has any apps which can handle a url. If it doesn't, then you disable clicking links on the `TextView` for that user.

Comment: Yeah, but I need it clickable and it works on most devices. I mean I surprised a bit (ok, its android, it will always be filled with bunches of bugs) but I wish to handle such situations if its possible to avoid app crash... So its not about disallowing urls clicking its about how to avoid app crash in such situations.

Comment: See my edit. You just check if the user has any valid apps for that `Intent` signature and disable linking if not.

Comment: This works in my case cuz I can decive to apply or don't the setMovementMethod(). However for URLSpan the matiash's answer is better choice.