# Android display html string by a TextView link

Tags: java, android, html, textview

I want to create an android  link (with a certain name) that show a given html string in a local web browser. I need to use TextView but it seems to not work.

that's what I get from the logs:

URLSpan : Actvity was not found for intent, Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat= here is the html string

this is the code:

link = "<a href="" + HtmlString + "">"
+ link_name + "";

TextView name = ((TextView) findViewById(relevent_int));

```
            name.setText(Html.fromHtml(link, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
```

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/26747105/3022836](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26747105/3022836)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to browse to a website, so make sure the the URL is well-formed as "http://whatever" or "https://whatever". Here is an example:

```
val urlString = "https://stackoverflow.com"
val link_name = "Stack Overflow"
val link = "This is the link: <a href=\"" + urlString + "\">" + link_name + "</>"
```

This will browse to Stack Overflow. If you still have trouble, check the URL in the debugger to make sure it has the correct format.